# jQuery ajax post when change select option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to catch when a user choose a parameters from a select option list to change the value of an image so can be set to 0, 1, 2 etc..

This is my table with all the data loaded from DB:

```
  <?php if(count($local) >0 ){ 
      foreach($local as $row => $val ){ ?>

<tr>
    <td> <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $val['images']; ?>" width="50" height="50" /> </td>

    <td> <select id="ddlViewBy" class="ddlView" onchange="categoryIMG('<?php echo $val['images']; ?>');" name="main[<?php echo $val['id']; ?>]" >
        <option value="0" <?php if($val['main_image'] == 0){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>No</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if($val['main_image'] == 1){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> >Facebook </option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($val['main_image'] == 2){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> >Filosofia </option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($val['main_image'] == 3){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> >Galleria </option>
    </select> </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my jquery code called on change:

```
function categoryIMG(id){
        var local =  <?php echo $this->id; ?>;
        var val = $('select').bind('change',function() {
            var newval = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>backend/chg_img/" +id+"/"+newval+"/"+local,
                    data:{},
                    success: function(result){ alert('Successfully called');},
                    error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
                    });
            });

}
```

The problem is: Some times take too much time to make the ajax call, and some times make 3 or 4 calls when user interact just one time with the select option.

I've try also the `.on('change', function())` and the `.change(function())` but I have the same problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are adding `$('select').bind('change',function() {` each time user is selecting the option from select box. Instead of this just modify your HTML to remove `onchange="categoryIMG(` from your select box and move `$('select').bind('change',function() {` to `$(document).ready(function(){` block.

Comment: That's ok but I have 2 script one to change image section area (script above) and one to change image category, so if i put all two in a document ready are called togheter when interact in one of the two select options..

Comment: can I see your 2nd script to change image category. But I believe it should work by putting both script inside single `$('select').bind('change',function() {` code block.

Comment: the second script is stille the same of the first one, 
function categoryGallery(id){
     var local =  <?php echo $this->id; ?>;
     var val = $('select').bind('change',function() {
         var newval = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>backend/chg_catimg/" +id+"/"+newval+"/"+local,
           data:{},
           success: function(data){}
          });
     });
     
   }

Comment: By looking at your 2nd function; I am visualizing your code logic as : "If option within select box with id = ddlViewBy gets selected/change then fire 2 Ajax call, one for 'backend/chg_img/' and other for 'backend/chg_catimg/'". Please correct me if I am wrong. If my assumption is correct then Yes... you just need to add 2 `$.ajax({})` blocks one below other within single `$('select').on('change',function() {` block

Comment: i was thinking the same as you infact i've fixed inserting all in the document ready function where I catch wich select option is selected with: var select = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id'); then i've an if else where i do the ajax call. Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed `var id`. Try this code

```
$('select').on('change',function() {
    var loc =  <?php echo $this->id; ?>;
    var newval = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>backend/chg_img/" +id+"/"+newval+"/"+local,
        data:{},
        success: function(result){ alert('Successfully called');},
        error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
    });
});
```

Comment: var id is passed from onchange function to the function categoryIMG. i've also try the .on and .change function but are not working good, with .bind is working good but is repeated 3\4 times for each interaction with the select option